# Spring inject xml mapper into test that is used by default

Tags: xml, spring-boot, testing

I created a simple service that consumes xml (i generated model with jaxb from https://krankenhausstandorte.de/storage/templates/xsds/Standortverzeichnis.xsd)

Using [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-webclient.html) i can easily read into desired Object:

```
public Standortverzeichnis getAll() {
    return this.client.get()
            .uri(config.getPathfull())
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Standortverzeichnis.class)
            .block(Duration.ofSeconds(config.getSecondsTimeout()));
```

So there seems to be an ObjectMapper in place that is deserializing to Standortverzeichnis.class.

How to get this mapper injected into a test?
For json i just use `@JsonTest` and inject "ObjectMapper" into my test.
But using this and reading xml i get:

```
Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
```

So how to get the same mapper (with same configuration) injected into my test?